# Twitter video media upload not working : Error: HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I am trying upload and post video media to the twitter using 'twitter' npm package.

During this I am facing an error :

```
error  Error: HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request
at Request._callback (/Volumes/Office/Work/Pack3/developer/tweet-it/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:221:9)
at Request.self.callback (/Volumes/Office/Work/Pack3/developer/tweet-it/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Office/Work/Pack3/developer/tweet-it/node_modules/request/request.js:1157:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Office/Work/Pack3/developer/tweet-it/node_modules/request/request.js:1079:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

Codebase
Initialize library

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
```

All details generate through twitter app console.

```
var twitterClient = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});


function makePost(endpoint, params) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            twitterClient.post(endpoint, params, function (error, data, response) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }

exports.postVideo = async function (req, res, next) {
    var params = req.body;

    const pathToMovie = './medias/video_3_640x360_1mb.mp4';
    const mediaType = 'video/mp4'; // `'video/mp4'` is also supported
    const mediaData = require('fs').readFileSync(pathToMovie);
    const mediaSize = require('fs').statSync(pathToMovie).size;
    console.log('mediaData ', mediaData);

    try {

        var options = {
            command: 'INIT',
            total_bytes: mediaSize,
            media_type: mediaType,
        };
```

// This request about to complete

```
        var mediaInit = await makePost('media/upload', options);

        console.log('options ', options);
        console.log('mediaInit ', mediaInit);
        console.log('mediaInit.media_id_string ', mediaInit.media_id_string);
```

// This request is not working.

```
        await makePost('media/upload', {
            command: 'APPEND',
            media_id: mediaInit.media_id_string,
            media: mediaData,
            segment_index: 0
        });

        var mediaFinalize = await makePost('media/upload', {
            command: 'FINALIZE',
            media_id: mediaInit.media_id_string,
        });
        console.log('mediaFinalize ', mediaFinalize);
        var status = {
            status: params.status,
            media_ids: mediaFinalize.media_id_string
        };

        twitterClient.post('statuses/update', status, function (error, tweet, response) {
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            }
            req.twitterStore = tweet;
            return next();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error ', error);
        return next(error);
    }
};
```

Video Used :
https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/360/big_buck_bunny_360p_1mb.mp4

Reference : https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/tree/master/examples#chunked-media

Answer (score -1):

In the example contains three commands to upload a media:

1. INIT
2. APPEND
3. FINALIZE

The INIT and APPEND commands seems correct in your code but in the FINALIZE command has as input the media_id. If I have not misinterpreted the code, you should set this parameter with the 'mediaInit' object and not with 'media_id_string'.

```
  /**
   * Step 2 of 3: Append file chunk
   * @param String mediaId    Reference to media object being uploaded
   * @return Promise resolving to String mediaId (for chaining)
   */
  function appendUpload (mediaId) {
    return makePost('media/upload', {
      command      : 'APPEND',
      media_id     : mediaId,
      media        : mediaData,
      segment_index: 0
    }).then(data => mediaId);
  }
```

The second step return the mediaId and that object is used in the third step:

```
  /**
   * Step 3 of 3: Finalize upload
   * @param String mediaId   Reference to media
   * @return Promise resolving to mediaId (for chaining)
   */
  function finalizeUpload (mediaId) {
    return makePost('media/upload', {
      command : 'FINALIZE',
      media_id: mediaId  <-------------
    }).then(data => mediaId);
  }
```

But in your code you pass 'mediaInit.media_id_string' as value of parameter media_id:

```
var mediaFinalize = await makePost('media/upload', {
    command: 'FINALIZE',
    media_id: mediaInit.media_id_string, <-------------
});
```

Probably this is the error in your code.

Comment: You are combining two different codebases. By that way, it did not match the number of parameters. 
I have added the reference only from where I took the solution but if you look at `function makePost(endpoint, params)` you will get a better idea what I am doing.

Comment: I found the problem. I used your code for doing some tests. As indicated in this post of twitter community https://twittercommunity.com/t/chunk-video-upload-finalize-returns-400-bad-request-error/61355/5, the problem seems to be caused by the video that does not pass validation. With another video, the script will works